# How to properly send and handle a JSON object in an ASP.NET MVC controller?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, model-binding

I am using ASP.NET MVC 4 and I am trying to send a JSON object to a controller that accepts

Here is my javascript and jQuery:

```
var jsonObject = {
    "PlantShipTo":{
        "PlantID" : shipToID.toString()
    }
};

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    timeout: 15000,
    url: "/Transfer/TransferOut",
    data: JSON.stringify(jsonObject),
    dataType: 'json',
    tradational: 'true',
    success: function (response) {
    }
});
```

In my controller I am accepting an object of type "PlantShipTo" defined below:

```
public class PlantShipTo
{
    public int PlantID { get; set; }
}
```

For brevity, I will only show the controller definition:

```
public ActionResult TransferOut(PlantShipTo shipto)
{
    PlantShipTo p = shipto;
```

I expect the MVC model binding to recognize the JSON as a PlantShipTo object, but the object is null when I check it in the controller.  Below is some of my request info courtesy of Fiddler.  The JSON looks like it matches my "PlantShipTo" class.  What am I missing ?

```
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
{"PlantShipTo":{"PlantID":"2"}}
```

Comment: `tradational` or `traditional`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MVC can automatically model bind only if the data you send matches the name of the parameter specified in your controller.

You can change the name of the root element in your JSON to match your parameter name:

```
var jsonObject = {
    "shipTo":{
        "PlantID" : shipToID.toString()
    }
};
```

Or remove the root element so MVC can automatically bind to the parameter's properties:

```
var jsonObject = {
    "PlantID" : shipToID.toString()
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You JSON Object is not so right. Check the correct one -

```
        var jsonObject = {
                "PlantID": YourVariable
        };

        $.ajax({
            url: "@Url.Action("TransferOut")",
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify(jsonObject),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            error: function (response) {
                alert(response.responseText);
        },
            success: function (response) {
                alert(response);
            }
        });
```

Output -

[image]